# SSJS to store API response to the DE

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am thinking of performing an API call to external webservice(I will collect the payload from a DE) once API call is done and response is received I would be saving the API response to the data extension, I have 2 options.

1. I can update a field on the source DE
2. I can pull all the values from source DE and update them on the target DE.

I have not built it yet, wanted to know if this is even possible, I mean what should be the workflow, it would kind of you if you can point out some platform functions too.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely do-able! Short answer, you would use the HTTP Request functions to call your API and return it as a variable. You then can try to parse that returned rowset/JSON to individual values or just load the entire Stringified value to a Data Extension field.

Long version. First I would recommend using SSJS as likely your API response is going to be a JSON. (if it is XML, then I would instead recommend AMPScript since it has [**BuildRowsetFromXML()**](https://ampscript.guide/buildrowsetfromxml/) function.)

For AMPscript though, you would be limited to the [**built in functions**](https://ampscript.guide/http-functions/) of HTTPGET AND HTTPPOST. These exist inside of SSJS as well, but SSJS has what I consider the best method to make API calls.

To make the call, I would recommend these two articles ([**this**](https://gortonington.com/integration-of-sfmc-with-external-service-via-ssjs-rest-api/) and [**this**](https://gortonington.com/restapimethodinssjs/)) from my blog for the details, but you essentially want to build out an HTTP Request call using whichever method required (GET, POST, PUT, etc) via the [**Script.Util**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpRequest.htm)

example GET function:

```js
function getUser(host,token,userID) {

    var url = host + '/api/users/' + userID;
    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 2;
    req.continueOnError = true;
    req.contentType = "application/json"
    req.method = "GET";
    req.setHeader("Authorization", token);

    var resp = req.send();

    var resultStr = String(resp.content);
    var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));

    return resultJSON;
}
```

Which should give you a response (assuming it is a JSON) of something like:

```js
{
  "key": "value",
  "key2":"value2",
  "array": ["value3","value4"]
}
```

Now, realize that this is returned as an Object (or Array), not a String, so if you try to Write it or otherwise output it, it will return as undefined. So to write out the whole thing, or push it to a data extension as a whole, you will need to Stringify() it first. Like so:

```js
var respStr = Stringify(myResp);
```

Note, that above uses the Core library version of the function, which requires you to load it via `Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1")`.  If you don't need the Core library, you can call Stringify via the Platform version like so: `Platform.Function.Stringify()` instead.

If you need to parse through it instead, you will need to use the following to collect information from the JSON.

For **JSON Arrays** `var arr = [z,b,c]` you will need to call based off of ordinal value (starting at 0). For instance, `var f = arr[0]` would output `z`.

For **JSON Objects** `var obj = {"key":"value","key2":"value2"}` you will need to call based off of the 'key' value (or name of the object property) to get the value.  For instance, `var f = obj.key` would output `value`.

You can also combine this, to something like (based off the example output from our get function: `var f = resp.array[1]` which would output `value4`.

There are some other functions out there to manipulate, sort or otherwise interact with JSON - but keep in mind that SFMS SSJS is run on ECMAScript 3 - so a lot of the more advanced ones will not work in it.

To upsert into a DE, I would use [**UpsertData()**](https://ampscript.guide/upsertdata/) if you are using AMPScript, or the SSJS version of [**UpsertData here**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionUpsertData.htm).